# Round cornered ImageView supporting background color in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to do a round corner `ImageView`. But I want it have background color (e.g., `#000`). With current solutions (either build an extended round corner view or paint a round corner bitmap) the background property will spoil the effect, as the view will be in a black rectangle (see the below image).

[image]

Is it possible to realize such a view that the background zone is also round cornered?

PS, why I want a background color: I allow users to upload non-square images but my image view zone is square, so I want a color to "align" them (see the below image - I want the red part to be round).

[image]

Comment: post the code you are using

Comment: Did you try to set `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` for you `ImageView` tag in xml file?

Comment: @mbelsky I want a background color, actually.

Comment: set your rounded bitmap as background of your imageView not src

Comment: @MHP But that requires me to encode a square bitmap with black background color, right?

Comment: Do you really want the background? I made my own round image view that "cuts" of any remains, so it's a true round inage view, not a square with circle display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounded corners can be done using Lollipop's outlines and pre-Lollipop paths. See:

1. Prepare masks

   ```
   if (cornerRadius > 0) {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
           setClipToOutline(true);
           setOutlineProvider(ShadowShape.viewOutlineProvider);
       } else {
           cornersMask = new Path();
           cornersMask.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
           cornersMask.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
       }
   } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
           setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BOUNDS);
   }
   ```
2. draw(Canvas) method

   ```
   if (cornerRadius > 0 && getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
       int saveFlags = Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.FULL_COLOR_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG | Canvas.CLIP_TO_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG;
       int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, saveFlags);

       super.draw(canvas);

       paint.setXfermode(pdMode);
       canvas.drawPath(cornersMask, paint);

       canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
       paint.setXfermode(null);
   } else {
       super.draw(canvas);
   }
   ```
3. and the missing viewOutlineProvider

   ```
       viewOutlineProvider = new ViewOutlineProvider() {
           @Override
           public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {
               ShadowShape shadowShape = ((ShadowView) view).getShadowShape();
               if (shadowShape == RECT) {
                   outline.setRect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
               } else if (shadowShape == ROUND_RECT) {
                   outline.setRoundRect(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), ((CornerView) view).getCornerRadius());
               } else if (shadowShape == CIRCLE) {
                   outline.setOval(0, 0, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
               }
           }
       };
   ```

And the image:

[image]

You can mess with this code in any way you want. You can cut the image and the background to any shape, separately or together. For more details check out the code on [github](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon).