# how to set a custom background color in a rounded imageview programmatically android

Tags: android

I have set a rounded image view [Rounded image view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28297409/6798867) and i don't know how to set a background color for it .I had tried set background method to fill the color in the image.

```
public Bitmap roundCornerImage(Bitmap raw, float round) {
    int width = raw.getWidth();
    int height = raw.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, round, round, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(raw, rect, rect, paint);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you post what have you tried?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30138503/5733111)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

This line will draw a canvas of **black** color. If you just want to change the color, change the rgb values. For e.g

```
canvas.drawARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)
```

will draw a red color bitmap canvas.

Comment: The first one actually draws nothing because you're using ARGB meaning you're setting alpha to 0

Answer (score -1):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageViewId);

// Set the background for the ImageView
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourdrawableImage);

// set background color
backgroundImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: I need to set a background color for the image which i have inserted

Comment: Have you ever tried setting these properties on a rounded Image view??

Comment: Yes @Sanoop i have tired

Comment: I was not asking you @KoVartthan

Comment: This doesn't work on a rounded image view.

Answer (score -1):

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(100, 100, 50));
```

Or else change the background color of parent layout.

Comment: Have you ever tried setting these properties on a rounded Image view??

Comment: This doesn't work on a rounded image view.